# Partway calculation along a bend

Tags: tikz-pgf

I apologize if this question has been asked.  I think it should be fairly simple, but I've looked around a bit and I can't find anything that does what I'm looking for.

I know you can calculate, e.g., the point 10% of the way between two nodes:

```
\node (A) at (0,0) {};
\node (B) at (1,0) {};
\coordinate (C) at ($(A)!0.1!(B)$);
```

But what if I were drawing a bent line between nodes A and B:

```
\draw (A) to [bend left=30] (B);
```

How to I calculate the coordinate that is 10% of the way along this bent path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\path (A) to [bend left=30] coordinate [pos=0.1] (C) (B)` to place a coordinate at a specified distance along the path:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {A};
\node (B) at (2,0) {B};
\draw (A) to [bend left=30] (B);
\path (A) to [bend left=30] coordinate [pos=0.1] (C) coordinate [pos=0.7] (D) (B) ;
\fill [red] (C) circle [radius=2pt] (D) circle [radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```